# mypy with dictionary's get function

Tags: python, mypy

I have some code that looks like this:

```
di: dict[str, float]

max_val = max(di, key=di.get)
```

When running `mypy` on it, it complains

```
error: Argument "key" to "max" has incompatible type overloaded function; expected "Callable[[str], Union[SupportsDunderLT[Any], SupportsDunderGT[Any]]]"
```

My *guess* is that this is because the return type of `di.get` is `Union[float, None]` *in general*, but in this specific instance, it should always return a `float` since the function is only being called on keys from `di`. The three workarounds I've discovered are to define a custom lambda function, ignore the `di.get` call, or `cast` it as follows.

```
get_lambda = lambda key: di[key]
max_val = max(di, key=get_lambda)

# ---------

max_val = max(
    di,
    key=di.get,  # type: ignore [arg-type]
)

# ---------

from typing import cast, Callable

max_val = max(di, key=cast(Callable[[str], float], di.get))
```

Is there a more proper/standard way of letting `mypy` know that the `get` method will not be returning `None`?

Comment: If your guess is correct, then using `di.__getitem__` would work b/c it raises on missing keys.

Comment: `__getitem__` is indeed the method you want here.

Comment: We know `di.get` won't return `None` because we're using information not available to `mypy`. The subtype of `str` implied by `di` isn't inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *dunder* (double underscore) member function `__getitem__` of a `dict` object is what you want here:

```
max(di, key=di.__getitem__)
```

raises no complains from `mypy`. The reason your lambda works is because it precisely emulates the intent of `__getitem__`, which is to implement evaluation of `self[key]`, as explained [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer, and the link to the docs.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark this answer as the solution so the question is properly closed.